# Div margin in desktop view only

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I am serving different WordPress themes to mobile and desktop users, and in the middle of each post, we display a 300x250 ad by inserting the following code via a plugin:

```
<div style="margin-right:20px;">
<script>...</script>
</div>
```

It looks great on desktop, but in mobile view, I am getting the following error: "Unsupported size for ad unit.  Ad unit is currently 280x250.  Minimum supported size is 300x250."

So the mobile theme seems to be squeezing the ad by the 20 pixels that are used as margin-right, which causes ad delivery to fail.

This is the relevant portion of the css that deals with media queries:

http://jsfiddle.net/sB4b6/1/

What should I add to eliminate margin for that div element in mobile view?

Comment: Why quick? Rather be good! I'd remove the inline style, add a class and go for a media query so you'll never go below `300px;`

Comment: *You shall not use inline stylesheets.* You can use [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) to do so.

Comment: The code is inserted via a plugin, so we need a quick patch to address this specific deficiency.  The theme and the plugin controlling the ads will be replaced in the near future, so creating a child theme to add media queries is beyond the scope of this issue.

Comment: Turns out we already have a child theme, so I can do it with media query.  I have edited the question to reflect that and added a jsfiddle link.